# Connect to Google Spreadsheet doesn't work | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

Okay so I have this code :

```js
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const creds = require('./client_secret.json');

async function accessSpreadsheet() {
  const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('1HrQBQU-3DtMywH_qZASB8xiIj8Vb6AlI3k2LWDameE8');
  await promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
  const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
  const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
  console.log(`Title: ${sheet.title}`);
}

accessSpreadsheet()
```

and the console return :
`> (node:1596) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: GoogleSpreadsheet is not a constructor`

Why ?

All the creds are correct and I still don't understant what is wrong...

Thank's for your help

Comment: Cuz you're requiring it wrong, it supposed to be `const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet')`

Comment: so now I've tried that and it says `TypeError: Cannot set property 'jwtClient' of undefined`@ToanQuocHo

Comment: Where is the error come from Maxon? Seems like it has nothing to do with the code that you added above.

Comment: Where are you setting the `jwtClient`? Can you share the whole code you are using?